# Transformerless power supply design

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, esp8266

I am designing a transformerless power supply for powering an ESP8266.

Requirement of supply:

- Input - 230 volt AC
- Output - 5 volt DC, 550-600mA
- Ripple: as much the ESP8266 can handle

I have tried to make and simulate the circuit but current ~283mA.

[image: Simulated circuit]

I need help in the following points:

1. Is it possible to design transformerless power supply that can provide ~500mA current?
2. Is this type of power supply recommended for an ESP866?
3. Please point out me the guide for designing these types of power supply.

PS: I already know the risk associated with these type of power supply. I am going to design it on a PCB and use in it an enclosure.

Comment: There are so many problems with your proposed circuit that you need to take a step back and justify why you need to use a transformerless supply. There is no guide for designing these types of supply because a guide that helps someone injure or kill themselves or others is as guilty as the person making the thing. And, for what reason? To save a dollar or two on a transformer? Does it really make any sense to do this?

Comment: Where is the fuse? You can buy tiny, certified [AC/DC converters](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/5vdc.html) internationally for very little money.  Go that route.

Comment: @andyaka  yup, u are right just to save cost of transformer(not see it as a single circuit, i just need to design it in large number)so that single dollar is going to become hundreds of dollars .Also  there are other factors too like size - overall dimension(including height) of transformer less power supply is quite small in comparison to the power supply that have transformer. size matters a lot for my usecase

Comment: None of the things you have said mitigate the dangers involved.

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia So you intend to make "hundreds" of these. Which implies that you are going to be selling this. Absolutely not. You can get really small board mount AC/DC power supplies. Did you even bother to look? This part is a 5V AC/DC power supply. Voltage range 85-305VAC input 5W. It costs $2.79. https://store.nacsemi.com/products/detail?part=LS05-13B09SR2S&stock=MS000000009217

Comment: @andyaka  please have a look at PCB image in this, https://www.amazon.in/Protium-Switch-Module-Compatible-Google/dp/B07W629D9R, they are using the T/F less power supply, from here I get the inspiration.

Comment: Being inspired by goods from Amazon is both sad and dangerous. Amazon, in my opinion are one of the worst examples to choose as a supplier of safe goods and I know this 1st hand. No cigar for this I'm afraid. Use a transformer.

Comment: Take a look at http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf .  It contains a discussion of both design considerations and safety.

Comment: I agree with @bunker89320 that you are probably intending to sell this as a commercial product. This makes it even more important that you will make this a safe product. You should not expose your customers to the risk of electric shock because you want to save a few bucks.

Comment: _"need to design it in large number"_ - Aside from all the other valid objections raised; a flyback SMPS design with an appropriate transformer is likely cheaper in volume than the gigantic X-rated capacitor (you _did_ look for X-rated caps, right?) you're going to need for this design.

Comment: Oh, and another thing; at 600mA out, you'll burn 2-3W in D7 if the esp8266 is idle, so thermal management will become a challenge. Honestly, just drop this design.

Comment: Is there also risk, if it is packed inside a well insulated closed enclosure(may be in acrylic or any other material)?

Comment: "**Transformer less** power supply" means transformer without power supply. You mean "**transformerless**" which means "without transformer".

Comment: Are you aware that this power supply provides no insulation from mains voltage? The ESP8266 must be regarded as live and an electrocution hazard. For examply, you cannot use any USB ports connected to the device or touch the IO pins. I think you are out of your depth on this.

Comment: Your value for R3 seems really low to me.  Seriously, 230V-mains bridge-rectified will be 322V, and the zener is 5.1V, leaving 317V across only 270 ohms?

Comment: @andyaka  https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LS03-K3B12SS.html  Please have a look at this, it is transformerless power supply,with quite safety approvals.

Comment: Who says it's transformerless? Who says it has any galvanic isolation? Who says that it is actually compliant with the documents specified? Who says MornSun are a reputable supplier? What quality control do they have? No, it isn't safe - they lie - look at the typical application section - they are breaking all the safety rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. is it possible - yes.
2. The ESP does not care about the source of the power as long as it is within its specifications.

3.There are many cheap 'smart home' devices on the market like wifi power switches and led lights that do exactly what you are wanting to do. They use power supply chips like the BP2513 to power the ESP8266. I'd suggest you get hold of one of these and open it up.

Realistically, at the price point of these devices it is not worth 'rolling your own'.

Comment: is this can provide up to 500mA ? if yes, how u get to know. I have not found anything related in datasheet ?

Comment: Maximum output is most likely thermally limited. You would need to do some calculations to determine if the bp2513 is suitable. You might want to investigate other suitable ics.